# Move MPMovieViewController full screen controls

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am writing an application that has an MPMoviePlayerViewController in it.  I want to use the full screen controls, but I am not displaying the MPMoviewPlayer.view in a modal full screen due to application requirement.  The issue is that the fullscreen controls appear 20px below the top of the parentView, ie as if they were calculating the status bar to be there.  The statusbar is there, but its location is already accounted for.  I want to force the the controls back to the top of the view where they belong.  However, I am having trouble finding anyway to access them from the object.  Is there a way to access the views that present the controls or if I want to fix this will I have to implement a custom control to replicate the apple controls?

[image: Image of Movie Player in Application]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IOS SDK has an example project that has an overlay view.  You could easily swap the close button in the example with a full screen icon.  It's not the easiest solution but it should work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I think I am going to end up building my own overlay of controls.  The requirements are for full screen controls only, no option to switch out of controls.  There are other overlays that we are displaying that block the default embedded controls.